# Enable/Disable Options Menu button with .setEnabled()?

Tags: android, android-menu, android-optionsmenu

Im trying to do something like this:

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    //multiListener = false;
    menu.add(0,START_DELETE,0, "Delete selected..").setEnabled(multiListener);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.multiselect:
        if(multiselect == 0) { multiselect = 1;
        multiListener = true;
        Log.d("DH", "index="+multiListener);
        }
        else if(multiselect == 1) { multiselect = 0; multiListener = false;
        Log.d("DH", "index="+multiListener);
        }
        fillData();
        return true;
    case START_DELETE:
        Toast.makeText(Notepadv3.this, "Pressed delete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    default: 
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
}
```

Basically, if multiListener = true; make "Delete selected.." pressable otherwise gray it out...

This simple , thing.. doesn't want to work out with me,

for somehow... the button is always greyed out, although Log says that, it changes to true...

Anyone, know something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call `setEnabled()` again to change item's state. Its state doesn't bind to a variable. This method should be called in `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`.

Comment: Thank you! This made the deed :)